# Bulk insert using AddRange in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am adding multiple entities in the database using `AddRange` in Entity Framework:

```
foreach (string tagNumber in notPresent)
{
    element = new TagMaster { Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), IsActive = true };
    element.TagCollections.Add(new TagCollection { TagNumber = tagNumber });
    newTagMasters.Add(element);
}
dbContext.TagMasters.AddRange(newTagMasters);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

What I was expecting is that by adding the complete collection in context using `AddRange` method, there would be a single query that will be sent to database. But to my surprise, I see multiple insert statements for each record to be inserted.

Any Insights?

Comment: What SQL statement did you expect to see?

Comment: I was expecting that all the insert statement would be sent in a single batch, and not one by one.

Comment: `AddRange` is just a shortcut for looping and performing multiple `Add` statements.

Comment: @DavidG:  Ok is there a way to force entity framework to create a single batch query for this scenario.

Comment: How many entities do you need to insert, is performance really such an issue here?

Comment: Is there any substantial performance difference between many single inserts sent separately and many inserts sent as one sql batch?

Comment: Currently for 30 records, its taking about 12 secs. I hope if all these statements are sent as one sql batch, it would be faster.

Comment: 30 records shouldn't take 12 seconds, there is something else slowing this down.

Comment: @DavidG at max I would be inserting 100 entities in a go.

Comment: `AddRange` & `AddObject` (used inside `AddRange`) are virtual so it can be overridden, but there is a lot going on inside it. I used ILSpy.

Comment: For a single reocrd, rows needs to be inserted in two tables. So in total to insert 30 entities, its sending 60 different queries.

Comment: I can insert thousands of records in the same time. Perhaps you will see a benefit if you set `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`

Comment: I had good results with using [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) - it uses SqlBulk instead, i.e. one query.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are running in is that sadly the entity framework commands know NO bulk inserts. Instead they generate 1 statement per line that you want to insert.
There is no workaround to this.

The only possiblity to get 1 single statement that does all the inserts is to use specific classes or libraries. As example here SqlBulkCopy which needs no external lib to be downloaded to work.

Here a link to the msdn site:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

The usage is quite easy. You only give the constructor your connection (after opening it beforehand!) and tell it what it shall write to teh server and what the destination table name is. Then you only need to close the connection afterwards again.

```
sqlcon.Open();
using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopyVariable= new SqlBulkCopy(sqlcon))
{
    sqlBulkCopyVariable.BulkCopyTimeout = 600; // 10 minutes timeout
    sqlBulkCopyVariable.DestinationTableName = "targetTableName";
    sqlBulkCopyVariable.WriteToServer(MyData);
}
sqlcon.Close();
```

The WriteToServer takes DataTable, DataReader or even arrays of DataRow. The exact implementation there would depend on how you want to give the data to it. So far from my personal experience: That class is quite fast and generates only 1 single statement. BUT it is only there for SqlClients. Thus if you  have a different client you need to look up which class or external library would be best fitting for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid insertions through Linq is not optimized as you would expect. It does that by multiple insert statements as you observed. You could instead bypass Linq in those cases and use the bulk copying alternatives instead (ie: for MS SQL server use SqlBulkCopy class, for postgreSQL use Copy etc).